# create stack Fragment view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

[image: FragmentView]

I am working on an application that displays the Stack View as shown above using Fragments. However after scouring the web I can not seem to find any implementation of this kind of layout.

Could anyone please let me know how to implement this stack view using Fragments?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone please have any ideas, its really urgent!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's rather a broad question...

As far as the layout goes, there'a a number of different ways to do it.  A broad outline for the landscape view might be like this (you'll have to fill in the appropriate layout height, widths and weights)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        class="net.test.program.Fragment1" />
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:name="net.test.program.Fragment2"/>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:name="net.test.program.Fragment3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For the portrait view simply reverse the two android:orientation tags and re-adjust your heights, widths and weights.  Then put them in the appropriate layout directories.